# How to visualise co-occurent words in a dataset using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, data-visualization, data-analysis

I am using Python and Pandas to analyse my data.

In my use-case, I have a text collection, and I have extracted histograms (280 dimensions) of words frequencies from the documents (one histogram per document), and all the histograms are grouped in one Pandas Dataframe (one histogram per row).

I wonder how can I visualise in a comprehensive way the co-occurence relations between the words.

Comment: You may need to show us a minimized example of your rows and the expected output.

Comment: [Visualizing GraphLab's LDA TopicModel with pyLDAvis](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/notebooks/GraphLab.ipynb)